# $\ast$-isomorphic between two $C^\ast$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let's consider the following unitization of the following $C^\ast$-algebra. Denote it
$\bar{\mathscr{A}}=\mathscr{A}\oplus\mathbb{C}$ with
$$(a,\lambda)(b,\mu)=(ab+\lambda b+\mu a,\lambda \mu) \text{ and } (a,\lambda)^\ast=(a^\ast,\bar{\lambda})$$
We know that this is a $\ast$-algebra with unit $(0,1)$.

Consider now $\bar{\mathscr{A}'}=\mathscr{A}\oplus\mathbb{C}$ and suppose that this IS unital. Then
$$(a,\lambda)(b,\mu)=(ab,\lambda \mu) \text{ and } (a,\lambda)^\ast=(a^\ast,\bar{\lambda})$$
This has unit $(1,1)$.

I just want to know if $\bar{\mathscr{A}}$ is a $\ast$-isomorphic to $\bar{\mathscr{A}}'$ in a unit preserving manner.

Comment: Your 2nd part about $\bar{\mathscr{A}'}$ is not clear. Who is supposed to be unital? $\bar{\mathscr{A}'}$? But this does not imply that its multiplication and unit are what you wrote (they could as well be those of $\bar{\mathscr{A}}$), and it does not even imply that $\mathscr{A}$ has a unit (the first component of your $(1,1)$). May be you should *define* the multiplication of $\bar{\mathscr{A}'}$ without any such hypothesis, and ask whether it is isomorphic to $\bar{\mathscr{A}}$ *when $\mathscr{A}$ is unital*.

Answer (score 2):

Some notation first. Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra (which is equivalent with the direct sum $A\oplus \mathbb{C}$ being unital). Let $A_I$ be its unitisation and $A\oplus \mathbb{C}$ (so the unit is $(0,1))$ be the direct sum of $C^*$-algebras (so the unit is $(1,1)$). A $*$-isomorphism $\Phi: A \oplus \mathbb{C}\to A_I$ must preserve the units, so we must map $(1,1)\mapsto (0,1)$. Thus, the identity map on the underlying vector spaces will not work. What is the easiest way to map $(1,1)\mapsto (0,1)?$ Well, consider

$$\Phi: A\oplus \mathbb{C} \to A_I: (a, \lambda)\mapsto (a-\lambda 1_A, \lambda).$$
Check that this is a $*$-isomorphism.

Comment: (+1) That is what I intended to answer, but I was waiting for the OP to agree with my comment and clarify/correct his post.

Comment: Hi, sorry. I will remember that.
Well to show $\ast$-isomorphism we have to
1. Check for bijection.
2. Preserve the $\ast$-operator i.e. $f(x*y)=f(x)*f(y)$.
3. Being a homomorphism. I.e linear and so on.
Am I on the right track?

Comment: @NabbKitha Usually when you mean $*$-operator, you mean the involution. So you should check that $f(x^*)= f(x)^*$. For the rest you are right.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will try to work something out.